# How does the Dimensional Dervish feat work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, combat

I'm a bit confused about the wording of the Dimensional Dervish feat from Pathfinder: Ultimate Combat and its exact working.

Link: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-dervish/

> **Dimensional Dervish**
>
> You teleport with a mere thought, savaging your opponents as you flash in and out of reality.
>
> Prerequisites: Ability to use the abundant step class feature or cast dimension door, Dimensional Agility, Dimensional Assault, base attack bonus +6.
>
> Benefit: **You can take a full-attack action, activating abundant step or casting dimension door as a swift action.** If you do, you can teleport up to twice your speed (up to the maximum distance allowed by the spell or ability), **dividing this teleportation into increments you use before your first attack, between each attack, and after your last attack. You must teleport at least 5 feet each time you teleport.**
>
> Special: A monk can use additional points from his ki pool to increase his speed before determining the total speed for this teleportation.

I'm confused and not sure how the bolded parts of the feat work exactly.

When i take my full attack with this feat, do i have to use my swift action for the turn to use abundant step or cast dimension door?

If I cast dimension door as a swift action with this feat, do i need the quicken spell feat?

Do I have to take the 5 feet teleportations between my attacks?

Can I just ddoor to my enemy use my full attack and ddoor back with this feat?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When i take my full attack with this feat, do i have to use my swift action for the turn to use abundant step or cast dimension door?**

**Yes** The text says cast it as a Swift action so you use up your one swift action for the turn to cast dimension door

**If I cast dimension door as a swift action with this feat, do I need the quicken spell feat?**

**No** you can do it because of this action otherwise the prerequisted would have said you need the ability to cast dimension door as a swift action

**Do I have to take the 5 feet teleportations between my attacks?**

**Yes** The RAW make it seem like it has to be at least 5 feet each time as there are teleportation increments between each attack and each teleport has to be at least 5 feet. I don't know if RAI would allow you to say an increment of 0 feet is not a teleportation  which would allow you to not move. Discuss this with your DM.

**Can I just ddoor to my enemy use my full attack and ddoor back with this feat?**

**No** based on the RAW reading mention above this is not allowed. You could ddoor in and ddoor 5 feet steps back and forth and ddoor back.

Comment: RE: "Do I have to take the 5 feet teleportations between my attacks?" This is the real sticking point, and—unfortunately—I'm reading it like you are. This feat should let you teleport in, attack a bunch, and depart safely, but instead it lets you teleport in, attack a bunch, then get stuck next to the foe because you're limited to twice your darn speed and each attack uses 5 ft. of speed! I mean, that's *sort of* pounce, I guess… except you *also* have to be able to cast *dimension door*! Stop screwing around and just cast a fight-ending spell already! Man, who *is* this feat for?!

Comment: You should add that because D.Door is cast as a swift it does not provoke

Comment: Also clarification in the last portion (about teleporting away) could be improved by stating more clearly they're allowed to teleport away, only that they (as otherwise discussed) could not perform the entire full attack from one spot.